# How to modify multiple elements of an array at once in GLSL

Tags: arrays, opengl, glsl

I have an array of ints where each element of the array roughly represents a pixel (its actually a 3D structure to give each pixel several values).

I'm trying to use a compute shader to modify all of these values which is then used by the fragment shader later on.

However if I have separate work items for each 'pixel' it is horribly slow. Since there are large groups of 'pixels' all with the same value I was wondering if there is some way to modify all elements within a range.

This is the sort of thing I want to do in pseudo-code:

```
array[5:5000] = 5;
```

Which would be equivalent to

```
for (int i = 5; i <= 5000; i++)
{
    array[i] = 5;
}
```

Obviously I don't actually want to do it with the for loop since they are very expensive in OpenGL shaders.

Comment: Strange, this is just the kind of data parallel stuff you would do per shader invocation, i.e. while processing a single fragment you'd set the value for a single array value. Could you post a little more code?

Comment: Would you like to see the compute or fragment shader code? This is what I've done in the compute shader instead of the loop I set it per invocation but if I have say 1200 * 600 work items (for each pixel) then the compute is quite slow especially if I call it per frame

Comment: Ideally both. How many layers per pixel do you have? Do you have to use OpenCL? If you got the hardware support (and since you're using CL/GL interop, I suspect you do), you could just as well use GL 4.4 and a shader storage buffer.